# root filesystem is full at 100% and not able to extend the voulme due to the same

Tags: unix, mount, disk-space

I am not able to extend the file system / root which is currently at 100% and I have tried to add a additional volume at os level

Even "`vgdisplay`" gives the error:

```
/etc/lvm/cache/.cache.tmp: write error failed: No space left on device
```

I am not able to find the any files that can be deleted to free up a little bit of space and also not able to extend due to the above error.

Also the `mount` / `umount` of a shared file system gives the error as the / root is at 100%

`mount` gives the error:

```
error writing /etc/mtab.tmp: No space left on device
```

`umount` gives the error:

```
umount: : device is busy. (In some cases useful info about processes that use the device is found by lsof(8) or fuser(1))
```

kindly please suggest here

thanks

Comment: It should be easy to free up a very limited amount of space - e.g. by temporarily moving  man-pages to another disk. This should be plenty to allow growing your volume online without the need to reboot.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend rebooting the system into a Recovery mode where you will be able to grow your volume.

---

If rebooting is not feasible, you could try the following steps:

1. `ls -l /var/log` — find a reasonably large (1/2GB) gzip-d log file(s) that you can temporarily relocate to a ramdisk
2. `mv /var/log/some_large_log_file.gz /dev/shm` — move the log file into a ramdisk under `/dev/shm`
3. **grow your volume** — should have enough space now
4. restore log file from `/dev/shm` back into `/var/log`

Comment: thanks for your prompt response.  its a production account with so many customer db tenants. if the normal reboot can help by any chance?

Comment: what type of unix system is this?

Comment: its a redhat 6.8      Linux version 2.6.32-696.6.3.el6.x86_64

Comment: okay I'll add an alternative approach to my answer, stand by...

Comment: ... what does `df` return?

Comment: [root@xxxxxxxxx /]# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg0-root  101G  101G     0 100% /

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106767/discussion-between-rtx13-and-rahul).

Comment: hi rtx13, I have updated the required info in the chat discussions. /etc is on root \ directory only, /var and /var/log mounted on to a different file system